# Checkstyle: Custom Rules - Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, checkstyle, spring-tool-suite

I have written few custom checkstyle rules using checkstyle API. They run fine using Maven (after I add the new project as a dependency to the checkstyle plugin).

Now I want these rules to be used by the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin. And this is where I am stuggling.

I've downloaded the sample plugin project (as suggested [here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending.html) and [here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending_custom_checks.html)).

I do not understand what to do next after reading these links.

1. Do I need to export my project as a JAR?
2. How do I plug it into my existing Checkstyle plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the correct links that will eventually get you there. As for your questions:

1. All your custom checks can go into one JAR file. That JAR file must be an Eclipse plugin JAR. I simply install it by copying it to the Eclipse *dropins* folder, but there may be more elegant ways to do that.
2. So you end up with two plugins: The original, unmodified Eclipse-CS, and your own plugin which contains the custom checks. When both are independently installed in Eclipse, the Eclipse-CS configuration dialog will offer your custom checks for use in Checkstyle configurations.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out some of it last night. I was hoping for one plugin doing it all. But no, looks like I need two. One is better for us, having many many dev's in multiple locations in my company, the simple the solution is, the better it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like following :

1. Create **plugin project** and add your **custom checks** there.
2. Make appropriate changes to **plugin.xml**, **checkstyle_packages.xml.**
3. Export the project as **Deployable Plug-ins and fragments**  (*Export > Plug-in Developement*)
4. Copy the jar file to *Eclipse Plugin* folde, so *no need to install your custom check* .

You can refer [this tutorial](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending.html)

Comment: A little more detailed explanation would've helped such as what should be put it in `plugin.xml` and `checkstyle_packages.xml` etc.,