# Custom Checkstyle check

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am trying to define my own checkstyle checks.
So I started with the tutorials [here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending.html) and [here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending_custom_checks.html) and downloaded this sample project: [link](http://eclipse-cs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eclipse-cs/net.sf.eclipsecs.sample/).

I imported the project in Eclipse and then I tried to export the unchanged project as a "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" and choose "Install to host" with the default repository.

After restarting Eclipse the new check didn't show up in the checkstyle editor.
When I import the default sample_checks.xml, coming with the sample project I get the error "cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate MethodLimit".

Also if I try to install the .jar via the "Install new software" dialog Eclipse says: "No repository found at ...".

So my problem is that I can't get my own checks working.
How did you managed to define your own checks and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting the Checkstyle plug-in in Eclipse to use your custom check](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23917915/1005481).